# Find fixed point of ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm trying to derive the expression for the fixed point to which x settles in general (terms of g and k). Given this ODE:

$\frac{dx}{dt} = g - k \cdot x$

So to find the expression for the fixed points I assume I have to make it equal to zero:

$0= g - k \cdot x$

$x = \frac{g}{k}$

However when I plot a few examples (e.g. for g=2 and k=3) and I check for x=2/3, the plot doesn't show a fixed point at this x.

Comment: What do you mean by "plot an example"? You have to solve (e.g. numerically) the ODE, and then plot *the solution* as a function $x(t)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the commenters note, the standard method in non-linear dynamics is to look at the direction field and its integral curves, and one can see the fixed point based on the patterns in the direction field (and indeed [classify them](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bifurcation_theory)) **or** one can look at the solution curve and see how the solution gets to the fixed point.

However, here, the ODE is sufficiently trivial to see this analytically.
We have
$$
\dot{x} = g - k x
$$
for $g,k\in\mathbb{R}$. Then the solution is:
$$
x(t) = \frac{g}{k} + c\exp(-kt)
$$
where $c$ is a constant of integration determined by the initial conditions.

As you noted, the fixed point is given via:
$$
\dot{x} = 0\;\;\;\implies\;\;\; x = g/k
$$
Well, notice that 
$$
\lim\limits_{t\rightarrow\infty} x(t) = \frac{g}{k} 
$$
So, yes, that is the fixed point where it settles over time.